# moving a file to a folder with root privileges in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, files, root, gedit

I am reading a tutorial that wants me to place a script file called `script.sh` into a folder called `/etc/profile.d/`.  However, when I try to save the `script.sh` file in that directory, the `gedit` tool gives me an error stating that I do not have privileges to save in that folder.  So I saved `script.sh` on the desktop temporarily.  I cannot even view the contents of the `/etc/` folder through the GUI.  (Unless it is empty and I am seeing truly empty contents.)  I can run the terminal as root by typing `su - root`, but **what do I type to either move the `script.sh` file from the desktop to `/etc/profile.d/script.sh` or to open `gedit` in a way that lets me save it to `/etc/profile.d/script.sh`?**

Comment: If you have the sudo package try `gksudo nautilus`, otherwise use `sudo mv -v /home/username/Desktop/script.sh /etc/profile.d/script.sh`  For more, try `man mv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `sudo` package try `gksudo nautilus`, otherwise use `sudo mv -v /home/username/Desktop/script.sh /etc/profile.d/script.sh` For more, try `man mv`

`sudo` elevates the command following it temporarily to perform tasks like you describred.

Answer (score 0):

You will need root privileges to save a file in that directory. Use the command 'sudo' if you have sudo privileges will let you achieve that.(sudo mv fileName /location/of/dir)
Yes you can use 'su -' change to root user and mv the script.sh to /etc/profile.d